# Why does else if and else act different here?

Tags: java, if-statement

When I do this,

```java
if(a>=b && a>=c) {
    max = a;

} else if (b>=a && b>=c) {
    max = b;

} else if (c>=a && c>=b) {
    max = c;
}
System.out.println(max);
```

It gives an error (java: variable max might not have been initialized), but when i do it like this,

```java
if(a>=b && a>=c) {
    max = a;

} else if (b>=a && b>=c) {
    max = b;

} else {
    max = c;
}
System.out.println(max);
```

It works. Why is it like that?

Comment: Because the compiler knows that it is guaranteed that `max` is set.

Comment: In Java, the compiler is required to actually prove that each variables is initialized before it is accessed (this was done to eliminate a certain category of bugs). But the compiler is only capable of doing this based on a limited set of assumptions. The compiler is allowed to assume that one branch of an `if-{}-else-{}` or `if-{}-else-if-{}-else-{}` statement is always executed, but the compiler is not allowed to analyze the expressions in the `if`'s conditions. This is done to reduce complexity (and it would probably have little gain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, all the compiler sees is that you have 3 conditional statements that set a value for `max`.  It therefore considers that there is a possible path where none of the conditionals is true, in which case `max` would not be assigned a value.

You and I can look at those conditions and understand that exactly one of them must be true.  The compiler doesn't consider that, it just assumes that each condition could be false.

When there's an `else` with no conditional, the compiler can guarantee that at least one of the assignments will execute.  Therefore there is no error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simple. An else will always be run when the if statements isn't truthy. Your IDE is complaining that max might not be initialized because it doesn't actually understand the code. To avoid it you could do the following:

```
    int max = 0;
    if(a>=b && a>=c) {
        max = a;

    } else if (b>=a && b>=c) {
        max = b;

    } else if (c>=a && c>=b) {
        max = c;

    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `max`.

Answer (score 0):

In else if, a condition is must. It goes inside only when the condition is satisfied. In first case, what if all the conditions are false then max will remain uninitialised where as in second case if both if and else if conditions are false, the else part will definitely execute. Hence max will definitely have some value in all the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, Java isn't sure that of the if/else blocks were executed. So, if you print out `max`, it might still be null. In your second example, no matter what the variable `max` will have a value (`c`), if not something else determined in the if/else chain above it.
This also depends on how you initialize `max`. For example, if you declare `max` like this

```java
 int max;

 if(a>=b && a>=c) {
     max = a;

 } else if (b>=a && b>=c) {
     max = b;

 } else if (c>=a && c>=b) {
     max = c;
 }
 System.out.println(max);
```

`max` never was assigned a value, so it's null. If you instead instantiate it

```java
 int max = 0;

 if(a>=b && a>=c) {
     max = a;

 } else if (b>=a && b>=c) {
     max = b;

 } else if (c>=a && c>=b) {
     max = c;
 }
 System.out.println(max);
```

Even if max isn't changed in the if/else chain, it still has a value to print.

Comment: "You could also surround System.out.println(max) with a try/catch on NullPointerException" - you're off-base here.  As a primitive `int`, `max` cannot be `null`.  The problem here has nothing to do with null pointers.

Comment: You're completely right, thank you. Just edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume your variable declarations look something like this:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int max;
```

And the variable uninitialized error is happening when calling max in System.out.println(max)
The most important difference is in this part:
#1

```
} else {
   max = c;
}
```

#2

```
} else if (c>=a && c>=b) {
   max = c;
}
```

So, for case **#1** compiler is 100% certain that even if you don't fall into any of previous if-conditions ((a>=b && a>=c) (b>=a && b>=c)) , you will end up in an else block, that will handle the rest of the cases.
For case **#2**, however, the last part of your if tree is still a condition. And the compiler assumes there is a possibility, where neither (a>=b && a>=c), (b>=a && b>=c) nor (c>=a && c>=b) are true at all, and thus, considers max to be left uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

In short: the presence of an `else` statement there guarantees that `max` is set.

The compiler applies *flow analysis* to check if a local variable is *definitely assigned*, and the compiler is smart enough<sup>1</sup> to detect that within all possible code paths `max` is set before it is used.

This is defined in detail in [Chapter 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-16.html) of the Java Language Specification.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> As Feuermurmel already said in the comments, the compiler does not analyze the conditional expressions. Logically, one of the conditions *must* be true, we humans know for sure. But such analysis of the compiler won't reach that far, probably to reduce complexity.</sup>